# Can we define the predicate "ordinal" in ZF-Reg. by recursion?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

Working in $\sf ZF-Reg.$ can we define the unary predicate "is an ordinal", denoted by "$\operatorname {od}$", meaning is a von Neumann ordinal, in a recursive manner?

The usual definition of ordinal is as an $\in$-well ordered transitive set, or equivalently as a transitive set of transitive sets that is $\in$-[well founded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation).

Here I'm contemplating the following definition by recursion:

**Define:** $ \operatorname {od} (x) \iff \forall y \, (y \in x \leftrightarrow \operatorname {od}(y) \land y \subsetneq x )$

In English: an ordinal is a set of all proper subsets of it that are ordinals.

My rationale is that in $\sf ZF$, where we have foundation, then clearly the above definition entails that every ordinal is a transitive set of ordinals, and so a transitive set of transitive sets which is well founded, therefore clearly a von Neumann ordinal. Now suppose that Regularilty fails, then for an argument by negation, suppose that we have an ordinal $\zeta$ that is not well founded, then the set $\operatorname {Ord}^\zeta$ of all von Neumann ordinals in $\zeta$ would be well founded and so a von Neumann ordinal, and therefor we'll have $\operatorname{Ord}^\zeta \in \zeta$, and so $\operatorname{Ord}^\zeta \in \operatorname{Ord}^\zeta$, which violates the well foundedness of $\operatorname{Ord}^\zeta$.

Comment: Recursion is inherently a well founded process.

Comment: Your "definition" of od(x) holds for any transitive set/class of well-founded sets. Note that well-founded does not mean well-ordered.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, the set $\{ \emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{ \emptyset\}\}\}$ is a transitive set of well founded sets, yet it doesn't meet the definition of $\operatorname {od}$ because $\{\emptyset\}$ is not a subset of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$. The point is that this definition would entail that a set meeting $\operatorname {od}$ is a transitive set of transitive sets that is well founded, and this is known to be equivalent to being a well ordered transitive set in $\sf ZF-Reg.$, and so a von Neumann ordinal.